# How do I establish a relationship between two objects where both need to have many of the other object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

My situation is this: I have two models, `Model` (as in car model) and `Engine`. I have some `Models` which have more than one `Engine` (different model years came with different engines), and I have some `Engines` which belong to multiple different `Models` (single engine was reused across multiple models).

Forgive me for being (very) new to Rails and ActiveRecord, but this seems a bit more complicated than just a `has_many` and `belongs_to`. I could be wrong. I should also note that I'm using `Rails 5`.

Given that I already have my scaffolds/models in place and I'd rather not delete them, how do I write a migration to achieve the above situation? What do I need to add to the respective models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use many-to-many relationship, make sure your migration name contains `JoinTable`

```
rails g migration CreateEngineModelJoinTable engines models
```

Engine class

```
class Engine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :models
end
```

Model class

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :engines
end
```

You can access it by

```
engines = model.engines
models = engine.models
```

Comment: This worked great, I'm surprised it was this intuitive. Thanks!